# Matlab- passing a constructed string value into saveas, can't get valid filename

Tags: string, matlab

I am working on a project where I read in an excel file, and I make a plot based on that data. I need to take the filename of what I open, add the letter 'a' to the end, then save my plot as a .jpg. The way I am doing it now looks like it should be working, but saveas doesn't like the filename and gives me an invalid filename error. Here is a sample of what I have working:

```
filename = 'C:\ExcelTest\T1.xlsm'
    >filename = 
    >    C:\ExcelTest\T1.xlsm
pathnfile = strread(filename, '%s', 'delimiter', '.')
    >pathnfile = 
    >    'C:\ExcelTest\T1'
    >    'xlsm'
pf1 = strcat(pathnfile(1), 'a')
    >pf1 = 
    >    'C:\ExcelTest\T1a'
%... data collection, plotting in f1 = figure(1), etc.
saveas(f1, pf1, 'jpg')
    >Error using saveas (line 81)    Invalid filename
```

Since I am changing the file I use a couple times, I really want to avoid typing in the full name to saveas if possible. Thanks!

Comment: You should separate your filename and your directory. So directory = 'C:\ExcelTest\ and your filename = 'T1.xlsm'. Because right now you're trying to save an entire path and not a filename.

Comment: unfortunately I need to save it in the same path as the file which cannot be the same path as my script. Is that possible?

Comment: not able to reproduce your problem. Your code works for me. (R2017a)

Comment: Sure, saveas(f1, fullfile(directory, filename), 'jpg') 
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/17580-how-to-define-a-path-in-saveas-command

Comment: I am R2013a, could that be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are making your life more complicated by rolling your own filename parser. I would go with something like:

```
filename = 'C:\ExcelTest\T1.xlsm';
[pathstr, name, ~] = fileparts(filename);
pf1 = strcat(name, 'a');
saveas(f1, fullfile(pathstr, pf1), 'jpg');
```